# Directx hInstance Cannot be passed

Tags: c++, directx-11

I am trying to learn the DirectXTK by making a basic engine, I am using dinput8.lib, dxguid.lib for input, when I try to Create the input interface by 
DirectInput8Create, the first parameter is hInstance. It compiles normally but as soon the app starts it gives access violation error (0x00005C).
Although it seemed there is no error.
Any Help!!!

Comment: If you are using the [DirectX Tool Kit](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK), then you should use the input classes provided rather than legacy DirectInput: ``Mouse``, ``GamePad``, and ``Keyboard``. See the [tutorial](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Game-controller-input) for game controller input and the [tutorial](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Mouse-and-keyboard-input) for keyboard/mouse input.

Comment: If you are using a Win32 classic desktop app, then you get the ``hInstance`` when your application starts in the call to ``WinMain`` (or the Unicode ``wWinMain``). If you are writing a UWP app, then you can't use legacy DirectInput in any case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't help you very much since you didn't provide any code, I assume your hInstance might be null pointer, but you can pass directly to the function this:

```
GetModuleHandle(NULL)
```

It will always give you hInstance of .exe file being executed